# Search all instances of Lowercase letters in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm attempting to find all instances of lowercase letters in a column in SQL, the issue is that I can't find a query that will perform what I want.

```
TestTable
  Col1   Col2
  apple  WALMART
  APPLE  TARGET
  banana TARGET
```

In the example above, I want to pull in the strings 'apple' and 'banana' in line 1 and 3, I'm trying to search for all instances of lowercase and not for literal strings.

```
select * from testtable where lower(col1) LIKE '%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%' ;
```

the query above returns 0 results. Any tips?

Comment: What do you want to see if a value has a mix of upper- and lower-case characters; or whitespace, or punctuation, in addition to lower-case characters? Are you trying to find values that *only* contain lower-case, or which have any lower-case - and if the latter do you want the whole value or just the lower-case bits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LIKE` condition does not use regular expression patterns. You're looking for the exact string `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]` appearing anywhere in the column value. None of your examples contain that, so now rows are returned.

You're also converting the column value to lowercase, which kind of defeats what you said you're doing, as you're converting `APPLE` to `apple` which will obviously then include lower-case characters.

To use patterns you need to use the regular expression equivalent, `REGEXP_LIKE`; the equivalent of what you did (I think - assuming you want to find any lower-case characters, not *just* lower-case):

```
select *
from testtable
where regexp_like (col1, '[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]');

COL1   COL2   
------ -------
apple  WALMART
banana TARGET
```

or using a safer approach with a character class:

```
select *
from testtable
where regexp_like (col1, '[[:lower:]]');
```

or with the opposite approach of excluding upper-case, which would allow whitespace, punctuation etc. to remain:

```
select *
from testtable
where regexp_like (col1, '[^[:upper:]]');
```

or to exclude any value that contains any upper-case characters at all:

```
select *
from testtable
where not regexp_like (col1, '[[:upper:]]');
```

which all get the same result with your sample data.

Comment: Still kind of new to SQL, but the query that omits all upper case did the trick! Thanks!